# What would the evolutionary and special traits would occur in a race of advanced alien mice?

Tags: evolution, aliens

An advanced alien species of intellectually superior mice has traveled to our planet, they are far more technologically advanced than us, so much that we can barely comprehend their tech, they have FTL ships and better weapons, but physically they are still just tiny (cartoon like almost, since they walk erect like us and use their paws like hands) itty bitty mice. What kind of evolutionary bodily functions, habits, distinct features, or abnormalities would occur in this species? Specifically, I want to explore what kind of special traits they would evolve that we don't have. What can they do that we can't? What can we do that they can't, or wouldn't, or what might they just find odd about us as opposed to them?

Comment: An addiction to cheese and building giant supercomputers with programs running for millions of years.....

Comment: Just don't let anyone build a hyperspace bypass through it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slarty felt honor bound to respond to a question concerning advanced mice life forms ;o)

There are often evolutionary left-overs from the past such as the appendix or a fear of snakes. Perhaps the mouse equivalent involves a phobia some or all of them have about things flying above their heads – a throw-back to some distant time when they were prey to flying predators.

Their small size would make temperature regulation and feeding of greater importance than in humans. They might well have evolved more elaborate rituals, procedures and controls than we have to ensure that their environment is kept as they like it at 26-34 degrees C and that they have their food available on a regular basis.

We might have thermostatic central heating and just leave a window open to cool things down. They might be a lot more fussy having elaborate temperature control systems back-ups and extensive monitoring systems for their comfort. Just leaving the window open could be the height of bad manners.

There might similarly be a greater emphasis on eating and rituals associated with it than humans have (and humans already do have a fair few). For example specific places to eat specific diets and quantities at specific times of the day and times of the year within set statutory limits. They might even have officials to oversee such things. Even if the systems had become totally automated such officials might still be held as honorary titles.

Answer (score 3):

They would live as long or longer than we do. Their communication skills and written history would equal or exceed our own. Their epiglottis will be lower than in earth mice, as descension of the epiglottis allows speech. Their brains, though small, would have enormous numbers of neuronal connections to allow complex thought. Their corpus callosum would be huge.

The features necessary for the advancement from individual organisms and groups to *civilization* is described [here](http://www.slate.com/blogs/quora/2013/06/21/human_advancement_why_has_so_much_of_our_progress_come_so_recently.html).

edit: OK, so difference between mice and people include that they are born blind. They reach reproductive age in 3 weeks. They vocalize outside of human hearing. They can walk up rough vertical walls. More intriguing mouse facts that may serve as food for thought can be found [here](https://onekindplanet.org/animal/mouse/).

Comment: This is a great start, I also hope to get some input on how these evolutionary traits effect their daily lives differently too. For instance, mice have teeth that always grow, so I think incorporating something like a "tooth stick" that they chew rather than a "toothbrush" would be an interesting difference, but that's about as far as I've gotten unfortunately.

Comment: Short reproductive age will probably not be the case.  Earth mice have a short reproductive time because they are at the bottom of the food chain and tend to die a lot.  But intelligence is unlikely to arise in such a situation - big brains take time to develop and intelligence is almost always connected with slow reproduction.  These alien mice might be small compared to us, but probably not compared to the life on their homeworld.